# Why does this weird combination of abstract classes and std::function usage crash only on droidx64 ship builds?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, c++17, abstract-class

Although the crash repros consistently in one build setup with droidx64 ship it does not in another droidx64 ship, so you probably won't be able to repro the crash. Trying to see what the differences are.

The one that crashes uses ndk-21.0.17
Forcing -O0 optimzation prevents the crash, -O1 onwards causes a crash.
It does not crash on any other platforms.

I'm trying to figure out what the differences are in the build systems.

This is the minimal code snippet that can reproduce the crash because things that prevents the crash include:

- Removing inheritance from either ITest1 or ITest2 , why though ?
- Removing m_callback or making it a shared_ptr, why though ?

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct ITest1
{
   virtual ~ITest1() = default;
   virtual void TestMethod1() noexcept = 0;
};

struct ITest2
{
   virtual ~ITest2() = default;
   virtual void TestMethod2() noexcept = 0;
};

using TestCallback = std::function<void()>;


class TestClass final : public ITest1, public ITest2
{
public:

   void TestMethod1() noexcept override
   {

   }

   void TestMethod2() noexcept override
   {

   }

private:
   TestCallback m_callback;
};

int main()
{
    std::make_shared<TestClass>(); // Crashes here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the shown code. This looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: That's what I felt as well. Wanted some confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: `StructWithCallback`?

Comment: Removed it. Initially m_callback was of type StructWithCallback. Was able to repro without the struct as well.

Comment: Try making the destructor virtual? Declare the methods virtual? Initialize variables like the `std::function` to `nullptr`?